# I am making a selection with ArcObjects, is there an Issue with iSelectionSet:AddList or do i have an error somewhere?

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I collect a set of OIDs into an OID array (long), this happens in a loop and if i find an OID i want to add to the array, I REDIM PRESERVE to expand the array.

```
iOIDListCount = iOIDListCount + 1
ReDim Preserve iOIDList(iOIDListCount)
iOIDList(iOIDListCount - 1) = pRow.OID
Debug.Print(iOIDList(iOIDListCount - 1))
```

Once I use this array to make my selelction via iFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.AddList **there is no error but a the resulting selection is completely wrong.** Instead of getting an expected 89 records the attribute table is reporting 40 is selected but only about 10 records is physically selected on screen and in the attribute table (see figure 1)

NOT WORKING CORRECTLY:

```
pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.AddList(iOIDListCount, iOIDList(0))
```

However when I use a For Next loop instead and add the OID's individually, I get exactly what I expect: 89 records. (see figure 2)

WORKS FINE:

```
    For i = 0 To iOIDListCount - 1
        pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Add(iOIDList(i))
    Next i
```

Figure 1 - Incorrect selection result when using AddList approach
[image]

Figure 2 - COrrect selection result when using Add (individually in a loop) approach
[image]

Comment: I've not used addlist before, normally I would use ISelectionSet.Combine with esriSetOperation.esriSetUnion. First I would create a selection set with the ones I want to add, get the existing selection set, combine then cast the selection set to the FeatureSelection. The help doc http://help.arcgis.com/EN/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/AddList_Method/002500000805000000/ states *"This method should not be called by .NET or Java applications. Instead, call IGeoDatabaseBridge2.AddList."*, I think this is why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you can no longer trust the [ISelectionSet.AddList](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddList_Method/002500000805000000/), according to the help document:

> This method should not be called by .NET or Java applications. Instead, call IGeoDatabaseBridge2.AddList.
>       [C#]
>       This method should not be used in .NET. Instead, use IGeoDatabaseBridge2.AddList.
>       [Visual Basic .NET]
>       This method should not be used in .NET. Instead, use IGeoDatabaseBridge2.AddList.

Which instructs to use [IGeoDatabaseBridge2.AddList](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddList_Method/002500000396000000/) which I can't find any examples of, but it looks like it goes this way:

```
iOIDListCount = iOIDListCount + 1
ReDim Preserve iOIDList(iOIDListCount)
iOIDList(iOIDListCount - 1) = pRow.OID
Debug.Print(iOIDList(iOIDListCount - 1))
dim pGDBridge as IGeoDatabaseBridge2 = New GeoDatabaseHelperClass()
pGDBridge.AddList(pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet,iOIDList)
```